# How to reference an object from string

Tags: java, string, object, reference

I got a button on a JFrame called button1.  And of course I know I can use a reference using the name....

```
this.button1.setBackground(Color.green);
```

But lets suppose I got 80 buttons on the screen and I got the name of the button in a string.

```
String name="button1";
```

And I need to do the same task of assigning an icon or colors or something to that button called button1.

In some place I saw a class named Object and (as far as I understood) I can transfer the name from the string to an object that will act like an alias of the button (at least that is what I believe).

```
Object button = new Object();
button = name ;
this.button.setBackground(Color.green);
```

But its not working at all. :(

As you can see (clearly) I'm new in Java so maybe I'm doing something stupid or maybe this is not the way of doing it.

I can compose on a string the name of every button on the screen, but I need to know how to reference that button from the string.

I will appreciate any help.